# How to convert String to code in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to ask, how can I convert a string containing a piece of code to actual runnable code:

```
  int x = 7;
  int y = 9;
  NSString *myCode = @"if(x > y) return x; else return y;";
```

I need to be able to run myCode as actual Objective C code. The example given is a dummy example just to illustrate the idea.

Comment: When you say "run" do you mean that you will parse and evaluate the expression or do you mean to convert it to machine code and have it executed?

Comment: I need to be able to execute it

Comment: You could call (existing) selectors based on string input, you could pass them some parameters based on string input, but you can not "compile and run some arbitrary objective-c code on the fly". Unless you are thinking of your own predefined scripting rules & parser: from your question it doesn't look like you had that in mind.

Comment: what I need to do, is to allow the user at any time to write a pseudocode of some rules and to be able to change the pseudocode into actual code and to be able to apply it. I know I can have already set rules and based on the input to choose a specified rule, but Im thinking of smg wider. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the objective-c is not Interpretive language, so it can't achieve by API.

Maybe can be accomplish by following steps

1. Use JavaScript to wrap c code
2. Use JSPatch[https://github.com/bang590/JSPatch] to run the code